# How can I have a video chat on my site like Gmail?

Tags: php, javascript, video, video-streaming

I'm looking for a free opensource project or just some code I can use to have video chatting capabilities on my site. Anyone know if this can be done easily, I know a lot about PHP and jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a jQuery webcam based I know:

http://mackers.com/571-jquery-webcam

Others:

http://www.jquery.wisdomplug.com/jquery-plugins/multimedia-jquery-plugins/best-jquery-video-plugins/

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/control-webcams-with-javascript-jquery/

http://blogupstairs.com/framework/javascript-framework/jquery/jquery-webcam-jquery-plugin-for-communicate-with-a-camera-in-javascript/

http://www.psd2html.com/blog/jquery-plugins-video.html

Comment: Is any free video chat available?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this can be done with PHP because the application which gets your Webcam's videostream must run on the Client, not on the Server. In this case, if you don't want your users to install special Software on their machines, you'll want to do it with Flash or a Java Applet.

I also found a [library which uses AJAX and REST](http://code.google.com/p/oovoo-video-chat/) to do it.

Comment: not sure why this got a downvote.... he's right that you'll need to use some client-side technologies like flash. php alone wont do it.

Comment: @Mark a very important part of video chat is coordinating server side, even if it is peer 2 peer. Saying it cannot be done with PHP is very unclear. Especially as the original question included jquery, which is a client side library. I believe the poster has some notion of client and server...

Comment: Even if you don't want to do it with a P2P Connection, you won't use PHP because it's not designed to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Native browser support enabled via Javascript APIs is under development and supported by Google, Mozilla, and Opera.  The project is called [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) (Web Real-Time Communications) and is supported in Chrome.