# Videochat site with PHP and WebRTC

Tags: php, yii2, webrtc

I should release a private video chat site with PHP.
I will use Yii2 framework to provide basic functionalities: user registration/authentication, Roles management.

Each user could open a public videochat session or invite another user in private videochat session.

The question is: what technology to provide the videochat? 
I see for WebRTC but all server  implementations seems to be only in Nodejs. Is There any framework or PHP layer that could be easily integrated with yii?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I have a video chat on my site like Gmail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923254/how-can-i-have-a-video-chat-on-my-site-like-gmail)

Answer (score -1):

This is duplicate question. You can find same stuff on this link.

[How can I have a video chat on my site like Gmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923254/how-can-i-have-a-video-chat-on-my-site-like-gmail)

You will need a client side technology with php like websockets with php.